# Black color comes instead a transparent background for textview in android

Tags: android, textview

The following two pics are a **TextView** with the following properties in it:

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:text="select password"
            android:textColor="@color/dif_black"/>
```

and the **button_style.xml** is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list >
<item>
    <shape>
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#88C425" />
        <corners android:radius="20dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

First pic taken from Canvas 2, Second pic taken from Samsung Galaxy Fame . Here is the problem I don't want the black color to be filled inside the **textview** border(Stroke). You would have noticed in the first pic that the background of the **textview** is transparent. I want this same in all android devices to be a transparent background.

[image: First picture with transparent background comes for Canvas 2] [image]

Comment: you need to specify the application Theme like Light.NoTitleBar etc...

Comment: Your TextView's background color might be transparent as you need even now. But what if Samsung Galaxy Fame's application theme is black? You would then see black with a transparent background of TextView, right?

Comment: Finally got it. I added this following code to the `<Shape>` tag of my style property. `<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have specified only the stroke of the Shape, but it needs background. It seems that black is default.

Change your **button_style.xml** shape by adding the solid transparent background:

```
<shape>
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#88C425" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</shape>
```

Comment: not working on button image background in <Button/> tag

Comment: @DavidDimalanta Thanks for pointing that out, is there any existing solution for <Button/>?

Answer (score 1):

For a simple **TextView** you could do this

```
(TextView) txtListChild.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

But if you're using a **ListView**, you'd need to find the **itemView** layout being used for each item and set it there... Something like this

```
if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need transparent color then U need to define like this

```
android:background="#ffffffff"
```

For Ex

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffffff"
            android:text="select password"
            android:textColor="#efyfff"/>
```

Or somply U can set your background to white

```
android:background="@color/white"
```

Update::

```
<Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffffffff"
                android:text="select password"
                android:textColor="#efyfff"/>
```

Comment: I need to see the background If I give `#FFFFFFFF` then obviously it'll be white. To see the background I've to use `@android:color/transparent` is there which did my work exactly. But I should use it in my **button_style.xml** not directly in `TextView` as you mentioned here

Comment: Set your background using "android:background="#ffffffff"" as mentioned above

Comment: Check my edit and #FFFFFFFF is not white color. This represents Transparent

Comment: @AndroidHacker have you tested color code #FFFFFFFF? It represents a white color not transparent color...

Comment: giving 8F didn't give me the transparent background it comes as white only. I gave @android:color/transparent which resolved my problem.. I got it.. anyhow thankyou for your reply...

Comment: Well it must give. Try this one for Transparent color "#00424242"